# Zuul routes by serviceId does not work

Tags: spring, routes, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, service-discovery

I met similar questions on different posts, but they are useless for me (no answer or no helpful answer). I'm going describe all details here and hope for help.

I use java8, spring boot 2.0.3, spring cloud elements are based on *Finchley.RELEASE* version.

In my test micro services application I have next services: *config-server*, *discovery-service* (Eureka), *edge-service* (zuul), *card-service*. All services loads at start time their own configuration from *configuration-server*. Services are started without issues.

*card-service* - gets random port at start time. This is a reason of configuring zuul rout to calendar-service by `serviceId`.

```
zuul:
  debug:
    request: true
  routes:
    card-service:
        path: /card-service/**
        serviceId: card-service
        stripPrefix: true
```

Using *discovery-service* client I detected next registered services `["edge-server", "card-service"]`. So zuul route uses same serviceId (`card-service`). The service name is correct because it is the same in *card-service* app `bootstrap.yml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: card-service
```

I use direct access to `card-service` by:

> http://localhost:59496/card-service/api/cards
>
> http://localhost:59496/api/cards

(i configured same result for it). - works fine.

My Zuul (*edge-server* is started on `8765` port) so I expect navigation by

> http://localhost:8765/card-service/api/cards

gives same result. But result is empty. Checking *edge-server* logs:

```
No handler mapping found for [/card-service/api/cards]
Last-Modified value for [/card-service/api/cards] is: -1
```

Check via actuator mappings for *edge-server* (http://localhost:8765/actuator/mappings - I've demonstrated here most interested part):

```
{
  "contexts": {
    "edge-server-1": {
      "mappings": {
        "dispatcherServlets": {
          "dispatcherServlet": [
            ...,
            {
              "handler": "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController@24a37416",
              "predicate": "/card-service/**",
              "details": null
            },
```

### Question

Is any idea how to fix route mapping for *zuul*?

Comment: The indentation of zull.routes.card-service is wrong. check zuulproperties section of :8765/configprops if correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was my fail. I thought I have configured it following tutorial, but seems autocomplete used `@EnableZuulServer` instead of `@EnableZuulProxy` in spring boot configurations. `@EnableZuulProxy` need to load configured `routes` for Zuul and everything works correctly than.